# Python crashes when running a log streamer using Qt

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, pyside2, qrunnable

## Goal

I have a process that logs on a file (realtime.log) while running and I want to print every new line of that file in my application in realtime. In other words I want to redirect the output from the process to the GUI. This means that I have **two different processes** running: the "engine" and the GUI.

I have already achieved this by using Tkinter but since I have to make a more complex, professional and good looking GUI I decided to switch to Qt for Python (**PySide2**).

## Problem

Python **often** crashes when I launch the GUI with the error message: *Python has stopped working*. The window starts printing the lines and at some point it stops working.

After many attempts and searches I got to a point where the program only crashes if I click on the GUI window. Moreover, the program doesn't crash suddenly but it crashes at the end of the engine's execution.

### Environment

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.5
- PySide2 5.12.6

### Code

Note that this is a simplified version.

```
datalog_path = "realtime.log"


def get_array_from_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        return lines
    except:
        print('error in file access')


class Streamer(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, stream, old_array, edit):
        super().__init__()
        self.stream = stream
        self.old_array = old_array
        self.edit = edit

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.stream:
                array_file = get_array_from_file(datalog_path)
                if len(array_file) != len(self.old_array):
                    for line in array_file[len(self.old_array) - 1:len(array_file)]:
                        self.edit.append(line)
                        # print(line)
                        self.old_array.append(line)
        except:
            print('problem in streaming funct')


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setWindowTitle("DATALOG")
        self.thread_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.edit = QTextEdit()

        self.stream = True
        self.old_array = get_array_from_file(datalog_path)
        self.streamer = Streamer(self.stream, self.old_array, self.edit)
        self.thread_pool.start(self.streamer)

        window = QWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        window.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(window)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.stream = False
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [@hyde answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876376/6622587) points out explains the reason for the problem but its solution is not applicable in PySide2 (in PyQt5 a small modification would have to be made, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561712/6622587)), an alternative is to create a QObject that has the signals:

```
class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = Signal(str)
```

```
class Streamer(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, stream, old_array):
        super().__init__()
        self.stream = stream
        self.old_array = old_array
        self.signaller = Signaller()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.stream:
                array_file = get_array_from_file(datalog_path)
                if len(array_file) != len(self.old_array):
                    for line in array_file[len(self.old_array) - 1:len(array_file)]:
                        self.signaller.textChanged.emit(line)
                        # print(line)
                        self.old_array.append(line)
        except:
            print('problem in streaming funct')
```

```
self.stream = True
self.old_array = get_array_from_file(datalog_path)
self.streamer = Streamer(self.stream, self.old_array)
self.streamer.signaller.textChanged.connect(self.edit.append)
self.thread_pool.start(self.streamer)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not too familiar with Python Qt, issue is probably, that you use a GUI object `edit` from a different thread. This is not allowed, the GUI part must all run in the same (main) thread!

To fix this, you need to have some other way for the thread to communicate UI changes. Since your *QRunnable* is not a *QObject*, you can't just emit a signal, but you can use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-2) on it's invokable methods. Please let me know if this works directly:

```
# self.edit.append(line) # can't do this from a thread!
# instead, invoke append through GUI thread event loop
QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.edit, 
                                'append', 
                                QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, 
                                QtCore.QGenericArgument('QString', line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As @eyllanesc stated, your solution is not applicable in PySide2 but the concept was definitely correct.